# How to search for object in PickerView

Tags: xcode, swift

I have Search Bar and PickerView. In Pickerview approx 20 items, i need to filter them by searchbar

Comment: You give very little context and even less detail, and I wonder if anyone knows what your problem is

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any off-the-shelf way to do this. You'll have to maintain an array of your original items, feed the text from the search bar into a filter statement, and then tell the picker view to reload using reloadComponent or reloadAllComponents.